# R how order DF "on the fly" with %>%?

Tags: r

Lets say I have this DF

```
   country confirmed
1  Germany     10910
2 Slovakia      1269
3       US    175663
```

and I want order by COL "confirmed".
How to do it on the fly within %>%  ?

workaround is this

```
DF[order(DF$confirmed),]
   country confirmed
2 Slovakia      1269
1  Germany     10910
3       US    175663
```

But how to do it this way `DF %>% order...`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, there is `arrange` to do the ordering

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- DF %>%
    arrange(confirmed)
```

-output

```
DF
#    country confirmed
#2 Slovakia      1269
#1  Germany     10910
#3       US    175663
```

If we don't want to use `DF <-` use the `%<>%` from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
DF %<>%
    arrange(confirmed)
```

---

Or in case, we wanted to use `order`, an option is to `pull` the column 'confirmed, do the `order` and `slice` the data based on that `order`

```
DF %>% 
    pull(confirmed) %>%
    order %>% 
    slice(DF, .)
#   country confirmed
#2 Slovakia      1269
#1  Germany     10910
#3       US    175663
```

Or another way is

```
DF %>% 
 pull(confirmed) %>% 
 order %>% 
 `[`(DF, .,)
#   country confirmed
#2 Slovakia      1269
#1  Germany     10910
#3       US    175663
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(country = c("Germany", "Slovakia", "US"),
confirmed = c(10910L, 
1269L, 175663L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3"))
```

Comment: great this works ! but excuse me you said that `If we don't want to assign back, use the %<>% from magrittr`  but this is exatcly doing this ... assigning back

Comment: @Andrew What I meant is the `df %>% arrange(confirmed)` only prints the output ordered into the console while keeping the `df` as the original one.  It can changed only by assigning.  The compound operator `%<>%` does the assignment as well.  What I meant `if we don't want to assign back` is doing `df <-`

Comment: ok, Thanks for help. Here is my working project http://webcovid19.online/

Comment: @Andrew it looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
> DF %>%
+   slice(order(confirmed))
   country confirmed
2 Slovakia      1269
1  Germany     10910
3       US    175663
```

**Data**

```
> dput(DF)
structure(list(country = c("Germany", "Slovakia", "US"), confirmed = c(10910L, 
1269L, 175663L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",
"3"))
```